# Child view not refreshing for changes on SwiftData model

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I have two models like these:

```
@Model
class Post {
    ...
    @Relationship(inverse: \Comment.post) var comments: [Comment]?
}

@Model
class Comment {
    ...
    var post: Post
}
```

And in one of my views I use a query like the one below where I show a list of posts and their comments count:

```
struct PostsList: View {
    @Query var posts: [Post]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(posts) { post in
                PostListItem(post: post)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PostListItem: View {
    @State var post: Post

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(post.title)")
        Text("\(post.comments?.count ?? 0) comments")
    }
}
```

When I insert a new comment with a given post, and then I go back to the view which shows the list of posts and their comments count, the count is not updated for the post I used unless I relaunch the app.

Is there a way to make SwiftData reload a given query, not when the entities returned changed, but when a related one did?

Comment: How do you count could you add the relevant code from the view?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've added more code regarding the posts list.

Comment: It turns out that if I render something using `post.comments`, then I get the updates. So I guess I should do something different when using `post.comments?.count` but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this but my target was macOS and when I added a comment in one window the count in the other window was updated but maybe this is different for iOS then.

Comment: I'm currently downloading the latest Xcode beta to check if something changed on this topic. If not, I'll try to prepare a simple repo which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson by creating a sample project to reproduce the issue, I found out that there is (probably) nothing wrong with the inverse. The issue is really in state management. Instead of rendering the given Post directly in the list, like I previously wrote in the post, I am actually passing each Post to a child PostListItem view. It looks like this is not the right way since the child view is not updating.

Comment: Do I have an option other than wrap the category in `PostListItem` inside an ad-hoc view model using the `Observable` macro?

Comment: Instead of `@State var post: Post` try using `@Bindable var post: Post`

Comment: @Bindable did not work for me, ended up wrapping as Francesco's 2nd solution.

Comment: Did anyone find any more information on this? I'm assuming it's a bug. I'm having the same issue myself and have resorted to using the `@Observable` wrapper for my child views which use a `@Model` object inside them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the issue was simply in the way I pass the single `Post` to `PostListItem`.

Given that I am not an expert in SwiftUI, the only two way I found until now to solve this issue are the following.

**Solution 1**: Remove the subview `PostListItem` and render each `Post` directly in the List.

```
struct PostsList: View {
    @Query var posts: [Post]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(posts) { post in
                Text("\(post.title)")
                Text("\(post.comments?.count ?? 0) comments")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**: Wrap the `Post` in a view model annotated with `@Observable` and use it as state in `PostListItem`.

```
struct PostsList: View {
    @Query var posts: [Post]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(posts) { post in
                PostListItem(model: post)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Observable
class PostListItemModel {
    var post: Post

    init(post: Post) {
        self.post = post
    }
}

struct PostListItem: View {
    var model: PostListItemModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(model.post.title)")
        Text("\(model.post.comments?.count ?? 0) comments")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any more information on this? I'm assuming it's a bug. I'm having the same issue myself and have resorted to using the `@Observable` wrapper for my child views which use a `@Model` object inside them

Comment: What is PostListItemModel? Can't you just use Post model directly.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Francesco's answer, I experimented with creating a simple property wrapper that gets the job done.

```
import SwiftUI

@propertyWrapper @Observable class ObservableModel<T> {
    var wrappedValue: T
    
    init(wrappedValue: T) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
}
```

To use (this also works out of the box with SwiftData `@Model` classes):

```
struct PostListItem: View {
    @ObservableModel var model: PostListItemModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(model.post.title)")
        Text("\(model.post.comments?.count ?? 0) comments")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your code and here is the implementation.

```
struct PostListView: View {
    
    let posts: [Post]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(posts) { post in
            NavigationLink {
                PostDetailView(post: post)
            } label: {
                PostView(post: post)
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Posts")
    }
}

struct PostDetailView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    let post: Post
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("PostDetailView")
            Button("Add Comment") {
                // add comment
                let comment = Comment(name: post.name + "Comment")
                comment.post = post
                post.comments.append(comment)
                context.insert(comment)
            }
        } .navigationTitle(post.name)
    }
}
```

One thing I noted that if I just put comment.post = post then go back to the PostListView, the list still updates but it takes a little more time (few milliseconds).

If I set both sides of relationship, meaning

```
comment.post = post 
post.comments.append(comment)
```

then the list updates instantly.